XML to JSON Policy fails to transform XML without error message
I'm using an apigee proxy to transform a third party SOAP endpoint into a restful JSON API.
My target xml file specifies the following policies:
<PreFlow name="PreFlow">
    <Request>
        <Step>
            <Name>JSON-to-XML</Name>
        </Step>
        <Step>
            <Name>XSL-Zoot-buildSoap</Name>
        </Step>
    </Request>
    <Response>
        <Step>
            <Name>XML-to-JSON</Name>
        </Step>
    </Response>
</PreFlow>

The request transformations are working great (the second one is custom XSLT).
The transformations on the response aren't happening. Here is the XML-to-JSON code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<XMLToJSON async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="XML-to-JSON">
    <DisplayName>XML to JSON</DisplayName>
    <Options>
        <RecognizeNumber>true</RecognizeNumber>
        <RecognizeBoolean>true</RecognizeBoolean>
        <RecognizeNull>true</RecognizeNull>
        <TextNodeName>TEXT</TextNodeName>
        <AttributePrefix>@</AttributePrefix>
        <StripLevels>2</StripLevels>
    </Options>
    <OutputVariable>response</OutputVariable>
    <Source>response</Source>
</XMLToJSON>

Looking at the debug session, XML to JSON policy is applied without error, but without changing the request at all:


The issue was that the response from the SOAP api was coming back without a Content-Type. Adding a policy to force the content type to text/xml fixed the issue.
